# How to set the width of the scrollbar inside a ScrollViewer in UWP?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a ComboBox with thousands of items bound to it.

The problem I'm facing is when I run the app on a tablet the scrollviewer's scrollbar is very thin hence I cannot hold and drag it and can only swipe to move inside the ComboBox.[image]

Hence I was wondering is there a way to change the style template of the ScrollViewer inside the ComboBox inorder to make the ScrollBar width larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to dig in to the style template and change some hard set properties for `Width` / `Height` that sit on the parts like the `Thumb` that you will find on the [default style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx). You can extract a copy via selecting a Scrollbar -> Right Click -> Edit Style -> Edit a copy. Save the copy wherever you need it, like a resource dictionary if you plan to use it multiple places or to the instance where you need it.

(Note: Generally folks start at the ScrollViewer level, then find a Scrollbar in it, and apply the style changes there so they can apply the style directly to ScrollViewers)

Once you have your changes made to the control template you then need to pass them to your ComboBox. If you only need it for the one ComboBox, You can just put the style template in it's Resources and remove the `x:Key` name you gave it so it hits the instance of the `TargetType` via inheritance for just that ComboBox.

However if you want it to hit EVERY ComboBox, then you'll need to edit the [ComboBox style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx) and add a reference to the Style template you just made to it's embedded ScrollViewer.

You'll find long tutorials out there for stuff like WPF/Silverlight that pretty much the same concept but little nuance differences in the templates and syntax of properties.

Hope this helps, give it a shot and if you get stuck come on back and we'll get you sorted.

Comment: I made the scrollbar thicker by editing the style template's width like you suggested, but the problem now is I can't hold the scrollbar and drag on a tablet(touch based device) which was my main intention. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @AbsoluteSith If literally all you did was change the width, that definitely should not be the case. You do generally have to give a ScrollViewer `Background="Transparent"` or a brush color to activate HitTestVisibility for the Viewer since UWP is more based on Silverlight itself if that's what you're actually referring to?

Comment: Yes all I did was change the width of the scrollbar it works well on the desktop where the mouse is used but in the case of tablet the scrollbar is shown but completely ignores the touch. I will try checking if I can see the HitTestVisibility for the viewer.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith You also changed the sizes for the RepeatButtons & Thumbs in the template right? The RepeatButtons are the tracks and the Thumb is the slider part thing.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Did you get the "holding and drag" the scroll bar problem for tablets fixed once increasing the size of the thumb? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @koopaking3 : Unfortunately no. The issue seems to be there. You might have to edit the way the scrollbar handles touch events in order to fix that.